# showing that a point is not an end point of any interval of the Cantor set

Tags: cantor-set

I know that for example the point $\frac{1}{4}$ is in the Cantor set. But how do I show that is not an endpoint of any interval in the Cantor set?

My attempt: At step $n$, we remove the open interval $$ (\frac{1}{3^n},\frac{2}{3^n})\cup (\frac{4}{3^n},\frac{5}{3^n}) \cup \dots \cup (\frac{3^n -2}{3^n},\frac{3^n -1 }{3^n}). $$ Therefore, for $\frac{1}{4}$ to be an endpoint of an interval in the Cantor set, it must exists an $n\in  \mathbb{N}$ such that either $\frac{3^n-2}{3^n}=\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{3^n-1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{4}$. But if we do the calculations for each of these two cases. There exists no such $n \in  \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $\frac{1}{4}$ cannot be an endpoint.

Is this a valid reasoning, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at only the last interval in your collection. The correct argument is to say that $\frac 1 4$ is not of the form $\frac k {3^{n}}$ for any positive integers $k$ and $n$: $4k=3^{n}$ would imply that $2$ divides $3^{n}$ which is not true. Since all end points of the intervals removed in the construction of the Cantor set are of the form $\frac k {3^{n}}$ we have proved that $\frac 1  4$ is not an end point of any of those intervals.

Comment: My reasoning for using the above expression with the union is that if we take the original interval [0,1] (call it $C_0$) and then remove the above expression, we get the $C_n$ cantor set. If $\frac{1}{4}$ is an end point of any of the intervals it must be equal to either the left or right point of the each of the open intervals we are removing for some n. And from that I get the two cases that I mentioned. But I guess that that reasoning is flawed then.

Comment: Could you explain how you arrive at $\frac{k}{3^n}$ and why the reasoning that you wrote in parenthesis pertains to the Cantor set?

Comment: What makes you say either $\frac{3^n-2}{3^n}=\frac{1}{4}$ or $\frac{3^n-1}{3^n}=\frac{1}{4}$. What about $\frac1  4$ being an end point of the first interval $(\frac  1 {3^{n}}, \frac  2 {3^{n}})$ for example. @user5744148

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now where I went wrong with my argument and why your argument is correct. Then since $3^n$ must be even and we know that any odd number raised to a positive integer is odd (by induction), $\frac{1}{4}$ cannot be an endpoint

Comment: @user5744148 Yes, that is what I meant.